# Bug: Triage not explained in "Access Review Queues" privilege

Tags: bug, help-center, privileges-page, triage

As far as I can see, the privilege to access review queues also gives you access to "Triage".

This fact is missing here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues

Comment: This is probably still in testing. Exactly one year has passed since it [was announced](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage), and looks like it's working well, so I expect some official annoucement soon, maybe a blog post, then they will also update the help center.

Comment: Yes, despite the help center text, this privilege certainly does give you access to Triage. However, I've been informed that Triage is only on StackOverflow, and questions should be directed to that meta site.